# Laravel foreach loop in HTML Blade Table Cells that Span Many Columns

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to show a table in laravel blade same as the image below 
[image]

In the HTML Blade table To make a cell span more than one row, I use the rowspan attribute. But when I try to do it with foreach in blade view it not working perfectly. foreach loop return the team raw three times.

here is my blade code

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="3">{{$data->team_name}}</td>
<td>{{$data->name}}</td>
<td>{{$data->email}}</td>
<td>{{$data->phone}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Team row returning three times, because it's in the foreach, if rowspan is a static value you can try below code:

```
@foreach($datas as $key => $data)
  <tr>
     @if ($key == 0 || $key % 3 == 0)
         <td rowspan="3">{{$data->team_name}}</td>
     @endif
     <td>{{$data->name}}</td>
     <td>{{$data->email}}</td>
     <td>{{$data->phone}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Laravel 5.2 and up**

For dynamic rowsapn, try below code:

```
@php
   $rowid = 0;
   $rowspan = 0;
@endphp
@foreach($datas as $key => $data)
  @php
     $rowid += 1
  @endphp
  <tr>
     @if ($key == 0 || $rowspan == $rowid)
         @php
             $rowid = 0;
             $rowspan = $data->how_many_members;
         @endphp
         <td rowspan="{{ $rowspan }}">{{$data->team_name}}</td>
     @endif
     <td>{{$data->name}}</td>
     <td>{{$data->email}}</td>
     <td>{{$data->phone}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

change `how_many_members` property fits to your model field name.

Comment: what should I do to make rowspan dynamic?

Comment: can you explain about your data models?

Comment: there is a table named teams which contain team name and how many members are register on there. another table named members which is connected to teams by foreign key

Comment: ok, you can use how many members registered field to achieve dynamic rowspan, is how many members registered field accessible via $datas collection??

Comment: can you give a example ?